# Как перевернуть на 180 градусов RGB в буфере?

Tags: c++, изображения, rotation

Некоторые веб-камеры снимают в перевёрнутом режиме. В программе нужно переворачивать такие камеры. Используемый алгоритм отражает изображение вертикально, в связи с чем меняется горизонтальное позиционирование:

```
void Camera::FlipFrameV(unsigned char * Source, unsigned short Width, unsigned short Height, unsigned char * Output){
    unsigned short Colors = 3;
    for (unsigned short X = 0; X < Width; X++){
        for (unsigned short Y = 0; Y < Height; Y++){
            for (unsigned short P = 0; P < Colors; P++){
                Output[(X + Y * Width) * Colors + P] = Source[(X + (Height - 1 - Y) * Width) * Colors + P];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Как сделать не отражение, а переворот на 180, чтобы сохранить позиционирование в кадре? (соотношение сторон 4:3)**

*PS: кадр изначально в YUY2 формате (`LPVIDEOHDR VHDR->lpData`), в RGB перегоняется после получения - может проще сделать переворот на 180 сразу с YUY2 (если да, то как)?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Точно так же, только еще оборачиваете X. Оборот по X и по Y в сумме дают поворот на 180.

```
Output[(X + Y * Width) * Colors + P] =
  Source[((Width - 1 - X) + (Height - 1 - Y) * Width) * Colors + P];
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!